# Is it safe to eat yougurt after the expiration date that smells alright?

Tags: yogurt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you know when a cultured item is no longer safe to consume?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6196/how-do-you-know-when-a-cultured-item-is-no-longer-safe-to-consume)

I have some yogurt that expired. Is is safe to eat it? Since yogurt has microorganisms in it would it ok to eat it?

Comment: I believe the linked question answers this pretty effectively.  Generally the answer is yes, it's still safe if it's not showing obvious signs of going off.

Answer (score 1):

Of course!

The expiration date is merely a suggestion. It might well be good for months to come-- as long as green moss doesn't start growing on it, it will be fine.

Comment: I don't know...The colonies of *Lactobacillus delbrueckii subsp. bulgaricus* will probably cause the dairy bits to get all semi-solid and taste delicious with fruit.