# How do I recognize that yogurt has turned bad?

Tags: yogurt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you know when a cultured item is no longer safe to consume?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6196/how-do-you-know-when-a-cultured-item-is-no-longer-safe-to-consume)

How does one tell when yogurt turns bad? Month-old yogurt smells the same as just purchased. The only visible difference is some separation. What are the rules of thumb?

Comment: I don't know what the official guidelines on yogurt are, but in my experience, yogurt, creme fraiche and other cultured dairy products never go bad in the fridge, because no bacteria other than their own culture can grow in them. You throw it out if a) you've got so much of its native bacteria that it is too sour and stinky (almost never happens with the mild yogurt in western supermarkets. Plus, it isn't risky to eat then, just unpleasant) or b) it catches mold (you see that easily).

Comment: Hi kzh, this question has actually been answered a couple of times here - see the linked question.