# I left yogurt on my desk

Tags: food-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you know when a cultured item is no longer safe to consume?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6196/how-do-you-know-when-a-cultured-item-is-no-longer-safe-to-consume)

I left yogurt on my desk for about 4 hours before I realized it (left my desk for some meetings), just now put it in the fridge, can I still eat it once it is cold or will it make me sick?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you'll be fine.  The yogurt would actually have to come into the temperature zone for harmful bacteria to become active, and then would have to have enough time for that bacteria to actually multiply enough to make you sick.  I have eaten room temp. yogurt many times.  You have nothing to worry about.